# What is considered to be a punctuation sign? Not allowed to use ispunct()

Tags: c++

I need to count the number of punctuation marks in a string but without including cctype/ctype.h, without using

```
ispunct()
```

(Stupid question:) Are these all punctuation marks?

**!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_'{|}~** found here: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_ispunct.htm

Is 'space' also on the list? I only thought of **?!,.;'"** not **$%^&**...

Comment: This is far too localized. If only we could still vote to close for that reason. Do your own crappy homework.

Comment: Write a program that checks all valid characters in your locale for `ispunct`, then copy the result to your own source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [cppreference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct) is pretty clear about what is considered a punctuation charachter:

> Checks if the given character is a punctuation character as classified by the current C locale. The default C locale classifies the characters !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~ as punctuation.

Comment: Printing out all non-punct, I see it's `!(isspace | isdigit | isalpha)` *and* not the backslash. What could be the reason for that last one?

Comment: But the question doesn't say "in the C locale".

Comment: @hvd There's a default locale though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, but there's nothing ruling out some *other* part of the code calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` before the OP's code gets called. If the OP stays in the default locale, that's relevant information that should be included in the question. (This is not really a criticism of your answer, it's one of the question.)

Comment: @hvd Which _code_ are you actually talking about?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the space character isn't punctuation in any locale (since that was a specific question).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Oh, I think I see what you mean. If the OP is writing a function to be usable in programs, then any other code in that program that runs before the function gets called might set a different locale. But if the OP is writing a program, then you're right.